# How to create a closure for a C function

Tags: c, lambda, closures, common-lisp, ecl

I am using the C API to interact with ECL and I am trying to create a closure object from a native function that has some stored state.

I have tried this:

```
cl_object f(long nargs, ...) {
    std::cout << nargs << std::endl;

    std::cout << "has value?" << std::endl;
    cl_print(1, cl_boundp(c_string_to_object("HI")));
    std::cout << "\ndone" << std::endl;

    return Cnil;
}

auto closure = ecl_make_cclosure_va(f, c_string_to_object("((HI . 2))"), Cnil);
ecl_defparameter(c_string_to_object("F"), closure);
```

This makes the function `f` callable with `(funcall f)` in lisp, but `cl_boundp` always returns `nil` inside the body of `f`. How does one construct the `env` (environment) parameter to `ecl_make_cclosure_va` so that the native code can read the values in the closure? I thought it was just an alist but apparently not, and I have found no examples of building one on Google.

Comment: Your code is C++, not C. ECL is for C, not C++

Comment: You probably should dive into FFI....

Comment: Also, note that **boundp** doesn't handle lexical variables, just symbols.  E.g., `(let ((x 42)) (boundp 'x)) => NIL`. Even if the C code is the correct CL translation, it won't help to translate the wrong CL code. :)  Common Lisp doesn't define very much environment introspection at all (though implementations very well may provide some).

Comment: One of the more common interfaces to environments is the [CLtL-2 environments API](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node102.html).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor so any idea how I'd get the value of one of these lexical variables with the ECL API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: I've added a second, fairly clean, shorter answer first, which probably doesn't quite do what you want, but might just be close enough. The original, longer answer which says why doing exactly what you want is complicated, but suggests a possible starting point remains afterwards.

**Easier approach**

I've outlined this in terms of the ECL interface, but it could probably largely be done with an FFI interface for a cleaner, more portable approach.

1. Define a c function which takes all the variables it needs, including the closure variables

code:

```
// defined here as a non-varargs function - you'll need to change it slightly
cl_object f(cl_object hi, cl_object func_param1, cl_object_fund_param2) {
  // note you can pass hi back to lisp fairly easily
  cl_object name = ecl_make_symbol("do-something-useful","CL-USER");
  cl_funcall(2,name,hi);
  // some other stuff
}
```

2. Wrap the function so it's callable by lisp (`ecl_def_c_function` ?)
3. Wrap the closure in lisp

code:

```
cl_object wrapped_c_function = cl_safe_eval(c_string_to_object(
  "(let ((hi 2))
     #'(lambda (x y) (your-c-function hi x y)))"),Cnil,Cnil);
```

4. Call the wrapped C function.

**Original answer**:

This is a slightly long answer to say "not easily" but:

The easiest way to understand what ecl does is use it to compile a simple script to C (`ecl -c <filename.c> -compile <filename.lisp>`). Here's a simple bit of lisp that generates a closure with a variable argument list

```
(defun make-closure-function (x y)
  #'(lambda (&rest arguments) (apply '+ (append (list x y) arguments))))

(defun main ()
  (let ((f (make-closure-function 1 2)))
    (print (funcall f 3)))
  (format t "~%"))

(main)
```

And here's the relevant parts of the C code it generates

```
/*  function definition for MAKE-CLOSURE-FUNCTION                 */
/*  optimize speed 3, debug 0, space 0, safety 2                  */
static cl_object L2make_closure_function(cl_object v1x, cl_object v2y)
{
 cl_object env0;
 cl_object CLV0, CLV1;
 const cl_env_ptr cl_env_copy = ecl_process_env();
 cl_object value0;
 ecl_cs_check(cl_env_copy,value0);
 {
  env0 = ECL_NIL;
  CLV0 = env0 = CONS(v1x,env0);                   /*  X               */
  CLV1 = env0 = CONS(v2y,env0);                   /*  Y               */
  {
   cl_object v3;
   v3 = ecl_make_cclosure_va((cl_objectfn)LC1__g0,env0,Cblock);
   value0 = v3;
   cl_env_copy->nvalues = 1;
   return value0;
  }
 }
}
/*  closure G0                                                    */
/*  optimize speed 3, debug 0, space 0, safety 2                  */
static cl_object LC1__g0(cl_narg narg, ...)
{
 cl_object T0, T1;
 cl_object CLV0, CLV1;
 const cl_env_ptr cl_env_copy = ecl_process_env();
 cl_object env0 = cl_env_copy->function->cclosure.env;
 cl_object value0;
 ecl_cs_check(cl_env_copy,value0);
 /* Scanning closure data ... */
 CLV1 = env0;                                     /*  Y               */
 CLV0 = _ecl_cdr(CLV1);
 { /* ... closure scanning finished */
 {
  cl_object v1arguments;
  ecl_va_list args; ecl_va_start(args,narg,narg,0);
  v1arguments = cl_grab_rest_args(args);
  ecl_va_end(args);
  T0 = cl_list(2, ECL_CONS_CAR(CLV0), ECL_CONS_CAR(CLV1));
  T1 = ecl_append(T0,v1arguments);
  value0 = cl_apply(2, ECL_SYM("+",14), T1);
  return value0;
 }
 }
}
/*  function definition for MAIN                                  */
/*  optimize speed 3, debug 0, space 0, safety 2                  */
static cl_object L3main()
{
 cl_object T0;
 const cl_env_ptr cl_env_copy = ecl_process_env();
 cl_object value0;
 ecl_cs_check(cl_env_copy,value0);
 {
TTL:
  {
   cl_object v1f;
   v1f = L2make_closure_function(ecl_make_fixnum(1), ecl_make_fixnum(2));
   T0 = ecl_function_dispatch(cl_env_copy,v1f)(1, ecl_make_fixnum(3));
   ecl_print(T0,ECL_NIL);
  }
  value0 = cl_format(2, ECL_T, VV[1]);
  return value0;
 }
}
```

It creates `env0` in `make_closure_function`, and makes it list with `x` and `y` appended. Then it calls `ecl_make_cclosure_va`. In `LC1_g0` (the wrapping of the lambda) it accesses the environment with `cl_object env0 = cl_env_copy->function->cclosure.env;`.

Note that the values in the environment are accessed because it knows the order, rather than being able to get them by name.

You'd basically have to replicate this mechanism to access closure variables in a c function (although you could generate an environment that stores the values in a mode convenient way (e.g. a list of `(HI 2)`).

Your best option would probably to bind bits from the environment as a special variable using ecl_bds_bind (see http://ecls.sourceforge.net/new-manual/re04.html). If you did that then I imagine you could use `HI`. Although beware it's dynamically rather than lexically bound.

It's a lot of work though! This really isn't a "user-facing interface".

Comment: So you can access the environment with `cl_env_copy->function->cclosure.env;`? That seems good enough, I can live with manually extracting variables with CADR and family. Thanks for the detailed answer.